# MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: workflow.compnies index: username_1 dup key: { username: null }

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, ejs

This type of question has asked many times .I have tried with every answer. In most of the case answer was like delete user index that is created by mongo automatically. I did it too many times. But  everytime  when I made request on server its created again(index).
when I write `db.compnies.getIndexes()`.I get

```
[
        {
                "v" : 2,
                "key" : {
                        "_id" : 1
                },
                "name" : "_id_"
        },
        {
                "v" : 2,
                "unique" : true,
                "key" : {
                        "username" : 1
                },
                "name" : "username_1",
                "background" : true
        }
]
```

After deletion by `db.compnies.dropIndexes({"username":1})`.I get
`[ { "v" : 2, "key" : { "_id" : 1 }, "name" : "_id_" } ]` as a `db.compnies.getIndexes()`.

after every new request above process is repeated.I am facing this error since last two days.I am not able to submit my data.
please help me.
Thank you.

here is my user model:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose");
// const findOrCreate = require('mongoose-findorcreate');

const logoSchema=new mongoose.Schema({
    url:String,
    filename:String
});
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: {
        type: String,
    },
       username:{
        type:String,
        unique:false
     },
    // password:{
    //     type:String,
    // },
 googleId : {
        type : String, 
    } , 
 name : {
     type : String,
    } ,
 firstName : {
     type : String,
 } ,
 lastName : {
     type : String,
 },
 age:{
     type:String
 },
 compny:{
     type:String
 },
//   logo :[logoSchema],

logo: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "Uploaded file must have a name"],
  },

 createdAt:{
   type: Date,
   default : Date.now
 }    
});
UserSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);
//  UserSchema.plugin(findOrCreate);

const User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
module.exports = User;
```

Here is my company model:

```
const mongoose=require("mongoose");
const passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose");

// const ImageSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
//     url: String,
//     filename: String
// });

const compnySchema= new mongoose.Schema({
    name:{
        type:String,
        // required:true
    },
    location:{
        type:String,
        // required:true
    },
    category:{
        type:String,
        // required:true
    },
    about:{
        type:String
    },
      logo: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, "Uploaded file must have a name"],
      },
      count:{
          type:Number
      }
});
compnySchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);
const Compny= mongoose.model("Compny", compnySchema);
module.exports=Compny;
```

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Are you asking "why do I get a duplicate key error?" or are you asking "why does this process create an index with a unique constraint on field 'username'?"

Comment: I want answer for both the question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce your condition.  I recreated a node program...

```
// npm install mongoose
// npm install passport-local-mongoose


var mongoose = require('mongoose');
const passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose");

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/nodetest", {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true});

var db = mongoose.connection;

//Bind connection to error event (to get notification of connection errors)
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'MongoDB connection error:'));

const compnySchema= new mongoose.Schema({
    name:{
        type:String,
        // required:true
    },
    location:{
        type:String,
        // required:true
    },
    category:{
        type:String,
        // required:true
    },
    about:{
        type:String
    },
      logo: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, "Uploaded file must have a name"],
      },
      count:{
          type:Number
      }
});

compnySchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);
const Compny= mongoose.model("Compny", compnySchema);
module.exports=Compny;
let compny = new Compny;

compny.name = "some company";
compny.logo = "some logo";

compny.save(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

If I run this program twice I get a duplicate key exception.  This is because of passport.  The program passport is enforcing a unique index on field `username`.  But you don't have a field called `username`.  This means the first record will get added with a null value (missing) for field `username` in the document.  The second document inserted also has a null (missing) value for the field `username` and thus violates the uniqueness constraint.

If the field `username` does not exist in the schema passport will automatically add a unique index.  But if the field does exist in the schema it will not add an index for the field - unique or not unique.  I suppose it is expecting the full definition of indexes including the unique attribute to be applied to the schema definition if the field `username` exists.

**Advice**:

- Do **not** apply passport to the companies collection
- **Do** use passport on the users collection.

Comment: Thank you so much now it's clear. During error solving when I added username field in compnyschema with unique true property  then it was worked for me but now I got answer  why it's working and role of passport in other schema.